# Mocking Pathlib write_text?

Tags: python, mocking

I'm writing a simple function to write out a dict to disk via some transformation and yaml. The easiest way to test what's going on would be to capture the output of `Path(file_name).write_text(text_to_write)`. But I'm having trouble understanding exactly what I need to do to capture this content.

```
def test_path_write():
    with mock.patch('Path.write_text', return_value=None):
        function_that_uses_path_write_text()
        assert 'Content I would like to be in the file' in SOME_KIND_OF_CAPTURE
```

Any idea how I get something into the SOME_KIND_OF_CAPTURE that I can use to test against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pytest, here's what I did:

```py
def test_writer(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(Path, "write_text")

    [...]

    written_content = Path.write_text.call_args_list[0][0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```py
with patch.object(Path, 'write_text') as patch_path:
    data_to_write = 'Something'
    patch_path.return_value = data_to_write

    path = Path('some/path')
    res = path.write_text(data_to_write)

print(res)
```

Comment: I think what I'd like would be to use something like StringIO to capture what was actually written - so it wouldn't be the return value, it'd be the value that Path thought it was writing out.